# Why can't I databind to a field?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I've just learnt (the hard way) that databinding doesn't work with fields. This isn't a problem given how easy automatic properties are, but I was wondering why this is the case.  Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a good explanation [here](http://www.nikhilk.net/DataBindingToPublicFields.aspx):

> ... because public
>   fields are not a recommended practice.
>   While they maybe convenient for quick
>   and dirty code, they do not version.
>   Using properties instead allows you to
>   change the access logic, and data
>   storage behind the covers, as well as
>   add validation logic when a value is
>   assigned. Furthermore, accessing
>   properties feels pretty much the same,
>   and do not have any performance
>   overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you use a [custom descriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/bind_entities.aspx), you **can** bind to fields. But I wouldn't recommend it

But data-binding is designed t be 2-way; with a field, there is no notification possible.